# How do I interrupt a RPostgresql query in R

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

What is the best way to interrupt a long-running query in RPostgresql?

For example, I wanted to see the first 10 rows of a table and meant to type,

```
  dbGetQuery(con,"
  select * from big.table
  limit 10
  ")
```

But I sometimes leave out the "limit 10" and then my program runs forever. Hitting ctrl-C or the stop button from my R terminal doesn't work. I either have to wait a long time and then see the full output print or I can abort the R process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to connect to Postgres with `psql` look for your query in `select * from pg_stat_activity` and then use `select pg_cancel_backend(long_query_pid)` to cancel the query.

Or you can use this queries inside R.

Comment: Is there a way to do this within R without going through psql (or RPostgresql)?

Strangely, the security is such that I don't have permission to cancel queries (even my own) on the server. The only way I can cancel a query is by closing my client.

Comment: @dchandler You can execute this queries from anything that can execute queries. I mentioned `psql` only because it is commonly awailable. As for permission this is what manual sais : "You can execute this against another backend that has exactly the same role as the user calling the function. In all other cases, you must be a superuser."

Comment: @dchandler Found that the quote from the manual is for 9.2 or later versions. In 9.1 or earlier it is restricted to superusers only.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Thanks for the suggestion. I think you're first answer is great and would have worked if the permissions permitted it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [RPostgres](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres). It fetches the data a row at a time, so you can easily interrupt it at any point.

Comment: can I add some extra increased timeout using this library?